# Kubernetes - File missing inside pods after reboot

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In Kubernetes I create a deployment with 3 replica and it is creating 3 pods.

After Pod creation I create a property file which has all the `key/value` that are required for my application (on all 3 pods).

If I reboot the machine the property file inside the pods is missing.So I am creating it manually every time if the machine reboots.

Is there any way to save the property file inside the pod?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see the following pages to help you get the most out of StackOverflow and the community; [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If you need further assistance please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: FWIW. The question would be understood by anyone knowing about Kubernetes. Not sure why it necessary to be pointing off to docs about asking questions. If the question is on a topic area you know nothing about, please don't go suggesting the questions is inadequate in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do depends on what the file is for and where it needs to be located.

If a config file, you may want to use a config map and mount the config map into the container.

If it needs to be long lived storage for data, create a persistent volume claim and then mount the volume into the container.

Something like this is necessary as the container file system is otherwise ephemeral and anything written to it will be lost when the container is shutdown.

Comment: Thanks Graham...I will try the steps that you have suggested...To Commit changes in a docker container:

sudo docker commit <container_id>.                                        
 Likewise is there any command in kubernetes.

Comment: No. You cannot through Kubernetes API create a new image from a running image as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your Update Graham ...Will try out the persistent volume and let u know the results.